# batch process not running windows server 2008

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008, batch-processing

I am trying to setup a task that will run hourly which will execute a batch file. When testing it manually it seems to run but not execute the process I expect it to. I was testing it to open mstsc.exe and I get the console message and a new console window open up showing the directory. Should not the actual RDesktop window open up.

```
@echo off 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq PRODUCER_69.exe" | find /I "PRODUCER_69.exe">nul &&(
echo PROCESS PRODUCER_69.exe IS ALREADY RUNNING! 
echo %DATE%
echo %TIME%
) || (
echo PRODUCER_69.exe IS NOT RUNNING! STARTING THE NEW PROCESS!
cmd /c start "C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe"
)
pause>nul
exit
```

Comment: Wonder if someone could help with an additional issue: if I wanted to check for multiple processes would I just recreate the second and third line for all or is there a shorter version.

Comment: Just created multiple versions of the lines below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oK I think I may have found my mistake...the following now works...

```
@echo off 
 tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq PRODUCER_69.exe" | find /I "PRODUCER_69.exe">nul &&(
 echo PROCESS PRODUCER_69.exe IS ALREADY RUNNING! 
 echo %DATE%
 echo %TIME%
  ) || (
 echo PRODUCER_69.exe IS NOT RUNNING! STARTING THE NEW PROCESS!
 cmd /c start "REMOTE DESKTOP" "C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe"
  )
```